# Should users give a reason why they are accepting an answer?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

Should users give a reason in the form of a comment why they are accepting an answer?

I would hesitate and say it should be required, but should it be strongly encouraged?

And strongly encourage by popping up a box if the asker hasn't commented on the answer they are accepting asking them if they want to give a comment why this answer works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason why a user accepts an answer is implied... The solution *works* and is the best/most elegant one provided.

If the solution doesn't answer your question but helps you solve it on your own, then you might want to provide a comment saying why you accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

It's assumed, and rightly so, that they accept it because it works. The reason is implicit to the action.

Comment: Here is an example about why an explanation by the author made sense and should be given.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296135/can-you-explain-what-this-code-fragment-is-doing  If the author didn't put it on people might wonder why accepted one got 1 vote over 14.

Comment: I don't think any of the comments on that answer helped explain anything. I participated in that discussion and I can tell you that the only reason that answer was accepted is that it happened to agree with the OP's opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If no answer satisfies your question, you can always answer it yourself and accept your own answer, explaining why none of the existing answers solved the problem.